# Implementing Android Licensing Library (LVL) in android studio 3.0.1

Tags: java, android, android-lvl

Can you tell me if it is possible to implement the Licensing Library in Android Studio 3.0.1?

I did internet research but all the answers are from 2013/2014.

If someone has an example project that can help me.

Or was LVL discontinued by Google?

If LVL has been discontinued, what is the best alternative to verify that an app was purchased from the google play store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LVL seems to be still present, you can download the tool with the SDK manager (I just installed in Android Studio 3).
Anyway, you can check your published apps in the [developer console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish)

Comment: I have everything installed in SDK Tools. Can you tell me in which package the LVL is included? Do you have any code that I can follow? Thanks

Comment: @ManuelRodrigues

Comment: @ManuelRodrigues Did you installed Google Play Licensing Library (version 1) from Android SDK?

If yes, you should be able to follow the [link] (https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/setting-up.html#download-lvl) application licensing

The LVL library project should be in:
<sdk>/extras/google/market_licensing/library/   (the LVL library project)